# Function not working within Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function that was created by a member here. It works alone in a PHP file. But as soon as I try and use it within my Wordpress template (single.php to be precise), it stops working (it outputs false no matter what). I've included both the original code and and the code as I'm attempting to use it within single.php of my template. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Solo:

```
<?php
// Normalize time to count from 0
function timeOfWeek($time) {
  if (!is_int($time)) $time = strtotime($time) ;
  $secondsInWeek = (7 * 24 * 3600);
  return (($time - strtotime('monday 00:00')) % $secondsInWeek + $secondsInWeek) % $secondsInWeek;
}

function isOpen($opened, $time) {
  $time = timeOfWeek($time);

  foreach ($opened as $openday) {
    list($open, $close) = $openday;

    if ($open < $close) { 
      if ($time > $open && $time < $close) return true;
    } else {
      if ($time > $open || $time < $close) return true; // Special case sunday -> monday
    }
  }

  return false;
}

$opened = array();
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('monday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('monday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('tuesday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('tuesday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('wednesday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('wednesday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('thursday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('thursday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('friday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('saturday 01:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('saturday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('sunday 01:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('sunday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('monday 01:00'));

$open = isOpen($opened, time());
var_dump($open);
?>
```

Within single.php:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if (et_get_option('lucid_integration_single_top') <> '' && et_get_option('lucid_integrate_singletop_enable') == 'on') echo (et_get_option('lucid_integration_single_top')); ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('entry clearfix'); ?>>
        <?php 
            $index_postinfo = et_get_option('lucid_postinfo2');
            if ( $index_postinfo ){
                echo '<p class="meta-info">';
                et_postinfo_meta( $index_postinfo, et_get_option('lucid_date_format'), esc_html__('0 comments','Lucid'), esc_html__('1 comment','Lucid'), '% ' . esc_html__('comments','Lucid') );
                echo '</p>';
            }
        ?>

        <?php
            global $wp_embed;
            $thumb = '';
            $et_full_post = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_et_full_post', true );
            $width = apply_filters('et_blog_image_width',630);
            if ( 'on' == $et_full_post ) $width = apply_filters( 'et_single_fullwidth_image_width', 960 );
            $height = apply_filters('et_blog_image_height',210);
            $classtext = '';
            $titletext = get_the_title();
            $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext,false,'Singleimage');
            $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];

            $et_video_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_et_lucid_video_url', true );
        ?>
        <?php if ( '' != $thumb && 'on' == et_get_option('lucid_thumbnails') ) { ?>
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
                <?php
                    if ( 'video' == get_post_format( $post->ID ) && '' != $et_video_url ){
                        $video_embed = $wp_embed->shortcode( '', $et_video_url );

                        $video_embed = preg_replace('/<embed /','<embed wmode="transparent" ',$video_embed);
                        $video_embed = preg_replace('/<\/object>/','<param name="wmode" value="transparent" /></object>',$video_embed); 
                        $video_embed = preg_replace("/height=\"[0-9]*\"/", "height=350", $video_embed);
                        $video_embed = preg_replace("/width=\"[0-9]*\"/", "width={$width}", $video_embed);

                        echo $video_embed;
                    } else {
                        print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext);
                    }
                ?>
            </div>  <!-- end .post-thumbnail -->
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="post_content clearfix">
            <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php
// Normalize time to count from 0
function timeOfWeek($time) {
  if (!is_int($time)) $time = strtotime($time) ;
  $secondsInWeek = (7 * 24 * 3600);
  return (($time - strtotime('monday 00:00')) % $secondsInWeek + $secondsInWeek) % $secondsInWeek;
}

function isOpen($opened, $time) {
  $time = timeOfWeek($time);

  foreach ($opened as $openday) {
    list($open, $close) = $openday;

    if ($open < $close) { 
      if ($time > $open && $time < $close) return true;
    } else {
      if ($time > $open || $time < $close) return true; // Special case sunday -> monday
    }
  }

  return false;
}

$opened = array();
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('monday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('monday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('tuesday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('tuesday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('wednesday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('wednesday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('thursday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('thursday 23:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('friday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('saturday 01:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('saturday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('sunday 01:00'));
$opened[] = array(timeOfWeek('sunday 10:00'), timeOfWeek('monday 01:00'));

$open = isOpen($opened, time());
var_dump($open);
?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.esc_attr__('Pages','Lucid').':</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link(esc_attr__('Edit this page','Lucid')); ?>
        </div>  <!-- end .post_content -->
    </article> <!-- end .entry -->

    <?php if (et_get_option('lucid_integration_single_bottom') <> '' && et_get_option('lucid_integrate_singlebottom_enable') == 'on') echo(et_get_option('lucid_integration_single_bottom')); ?>

    <?php 
        if ( et_get_option('lucid_468_enable') == 'on' ){
            if ( et_get_option('lucid_468_adsense') <> '' ) echo( et_get_option('lucid_468_adsense') );
            else { ?>
               <a href="<?php echo esc_url(et_get_option('lucid_468_url')); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(et_get_option('lucid_468_image')); ?>" alt="468 ad" class="foursixeight" /></a>
    <?php   }    
        }
    ?>

    <?php 
        if ( 'on' == et_get_option('lucid_show_postcomments') ) comments_template('', true);
    ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. This code just checks current time against the array to determine if current time is within the hours of the business. It works in a php file all by itself, as in, it returns true that the business is open. Within Wordpress, it returns false.

Comment: make sure you set your timezone correctly with [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). The server may be in UTC or GMT or who knows what else by default.

Comment: Already ruled that out, just now actually. Both alone and within Wordpress, the output is the same for time(). I also added in date_default_timezone_set just to see, and there was no difference.

Comment: Just guessing now, but I would dump the `$opened` array and make sure the numbers are the same in both the working and non-working versions, and also dump `timeofWeek(time())` (should be diff by a few seconds only).

Comment: A dump of $opened matched on both. Not sure how to dump timeOfWeek(time()) given that it's tied to the function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should move your function definitions outside the while loop, as the script will break as soon as there's more than 1 post. Next, make sure that your server timezone is correct. Everything else is fine.

Comment: I moved the functions before the loop, just after get_header(), and set the timezone with date_default_timezone_set. Still false.

Comment: Add echo date("H:I"); and check if it matches your current time

Comment: That didn't match. 21:16 output on the script on its own and 04:16 from Wordpress. So, why is that happening?

Comment: Do you have two different servers or both the script and WordPress are on the same machine?

Comment: Same machine, same virtualhost.

Comment: Can you log into your wp-admin and check the timezone? 04:16 is UTC time and that's what's set by default in WordPress. You can find it in the General Settings section of wp-admin

Comment: Timezone is set correctly. I even changed it to UTC-7 from city name just to see. No change.

Comment: So I echoed date_default_timezone_get() and it returned UTC, despite date_default_timezone_set being set correctly.

Comment: It appears that date_default_timezone_set( 'UTC' ); is hardcoded in wp-settings.php. I modified that and it works now. Not sure what impact this will have on Wordpress in general.